# GWT: No file found for *cache.js

Tags: javascript, caching, gwt

I was trying to launch my GWT web application and everything ran smoothly until I openned it up in Chrome. The console says:

```
    Dec 05, 2014 3:37:27 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
    WARNING: No file found for: *.cache.js
```

And my app froze at the loading page, did not open up.
Anyone had the same problem before? How did you resolve it?

Also when I opened it up in Firefox, the browser says that my app needs to be (re)compiled. I did clean/built and rerun but the same problem persisted.

Comment: So what do you mean by "everything ran smoothly"?

Comment: Sorry what I meant was that the console did not show any error messages until I entered the URL into the browser.

Comment: Show your script tag in the host page. There may be a problem with a module name.